# Binary classification model predicting non binary. What problem is with data size?

Tags: keras, neural-network, prediction

My binary classification neural network is giving 200 values on predict, but should give only 2 values . What is wrong I am doing?

```
print(modelAtt.summary())
```

Output is:

```
Model: "sequential_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 200, 300)          5400300   
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_3 (Bidirection (None, 200, 40)           51360     
_________________________________________________________________
attention_vec (SeqSelfAttent (None, None, 40)          2625      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, None, 40)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, None, 5)           205       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, None, 1)           6         
=================================================================
Total params: 5,454,496
Trainable params: 54,196
Non-trainable params: 5,400,300
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

As can be seen in dense_11 layer, output is binary .
Though when I run predict it gives like below:

```
modelAtt.predict(X_train[0])

array([[[0.19932884]],

       [[0.31575316]],

       [[0.15211353]],

       [[0.49087098]],
       .  .  .
       [[0.43889832]],

       [[0.43889832]]], dtype=float32)
```

for sake of simplicity, I just passed the training data itself as shown above. The length of output vector is 200, which is length of tokens in each row of train_X .
I have tried [X_train[0]] as well, but same output.

Comment: Look at your output, its 3D (None, None, 1), you should add a Flatten layer before the Dense to make it 2D.

Comment: Thanks.. that helped.. you can move comment to answer. I will mark it correct